Dual complex torus isogeny
Let $X = \mathbb{C}^g / \Lambda$ be a complex torus, and let $X^\vee$ denote its dual complex torus (there are several equivalent definitions of this object).
Now, consider the Néron-Severi group $\mathrm{NS}(X)$. We know that $\mathrm{NS}(X)$ is a subgroup of $\mathrm{Hom}(X, X^\vee)$. My question is whether all the isogenies between $X$ and $X^\vee$ are contained in $\mathrm{NS}(X)$. What happens if $\mathrm{NS}(X) = 0$? Is it still possible to construct an isogeny between $X$ and its dual?
For the last question, since $X^\vee \simeq \mathrm{Pic}^0(X)$, I am looking for a complex torus that is isogenous to its Picard group. This is because $\mathrm{NS}(X) = \mathrm{Pic}(X) / \mathrm{Pic}^0(X)$, and if this quotient is trivial, we would have $X^\vee \simeq \mathrm{Pic}(X)$. In that case, $X$ would also be isogenous to $\mathrm{Pic}(X)$.
I am looking for directions on how to approach this problem. Additionally, I would like to understand what happens if I take the quotient of $\mathrm{Hom}(X,X^\vee)$ by $\mathrm{NS}(X)$.
Does anyone know any references or where I can find approaches to this question? I have already read Debarre's book and Birkenhake-Lange's book.
